# Angular material table print view

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm using angular material version 9.2.4 and created a data table with pagination. I want my users to be able to print this table, I already removed every unnecessary element from the page with @media print, but the table's behavior is weird. I want my table rows to break to a new page if it cannot fit the page because of the number of rows, but it just skips the remaining data.

What I've tried so far:

1. Adding this to my css:

   ```
   table {
     page-break-inside: auto;
   }
   tr {
     page-break-inside: avoid;
     page-break-after: auto;
     display: inline-block;
   }
   thead {
     display: table-header-group;
   }
   tfoot {
     display: table-footer-group;
   }
   ```
2. Wrapping all table elements inside div, because I've read that the above CSS properties can ignore non-block-displayed elements.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){$("table tbody th, table tbody td").wrapInner("<div></div>");});
   ```

Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm close to a solution. Just to confirm, do you use a sidenav? In my case this has nothing to do with mat-table, and everything to do with the side-nav.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but this has nothing to do with mat-table. This solution is highly specific to the rest of your page but this worked for me. I have a sidenav component with perfect-scrollbar and this caused the height to be limited.

I added this to `master-layout.component.scss`

```
@media print {
  .mat-drawer-content {
    height: auto !important;
  }
  .mat-drawer-container {
    overflow: inherit !important;
  }
  perfect-scrollbar {
    height: auto;
    max-height: none;
  }
  mat-sidenav-container {
    overflow: inherit !important;
  }
}
```

More usefull will probably be the way I came to this. Open the DevTools of your browser and enable "Emulate CSS media Type", set it to "print". You can now inspect your page and the `@media print` tags will be enabled.

Now go over the elements and look at the renedered height. It should be larger than your window. If it's not, it must be limited by `overflow: hidden`, `height: 100%` or `max-height: 100%`. Adjust CSS so these are set to auto or inherit. Go up the elements untill none of the heights are limited to the window size.